# Generate new test data inside QuickCheck property

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm having trouble with a programming problem here. Half the trouble is that the problem itself is quite tricky to think about, and the other half is that I can't remember how to find my way around QuickCheck.

I know that if you write a function that takes several arguments that have an `Arbitrary` instance, QuickCheck will let you use that method as a test. What I can't figure out is how to generate new test arguments inside that method. I want to write something like

```
prop13 :: Foo -> Bar -> Bool
prop13 foo bar =
  if foobar foo bar
    then fn1 foo
    else newInput $ \ baz -> fn2 foo bar baz
```

but I can't figure out how the hell to do that.

Actually, no, what I *really* want to write is

```
prop13 :: Foo -> Bar -> Property
prop13 foo bar =
  if foobar foo bar
    then label "foobar=YES" $ fn1 foo
    else label "foobar=NO"  $ newInput $ \ baz -> fn2 foo bar baz
```

just so I can check it isn't taking one branch 100% of the time or something ridiculous like that.

Actually, what would be great is if I could demand that `baz` has some particular property. I vaguely remember QuickCheck having a function somewhere to throw away inputs not satisfying a given condition. (The only problem being that it might take an unreasonably number of attempts to satisfy the condition...)

Is there a way to do this? I'm staring at the Haddock page, but I can't figure out how to get what I want...

Answer (score 4):

> A property may take the form
>
> `classify <condition> <string>$ <property>`
>
> For example,
>
> `prop_Insert x xs =
>     ordered xs ==>
>         classify (ordered (x:xs)) "at-head" $
>         classify (ordered (xs ++ [x])) "at-tail" $
>         ordered (insert x xs)
>     where types = x :: Int`
>
> Test cases satisfying the condition are assigned the classification
>   given, and the distribution of classifications is reported after
>   testing. In this case the result is
>
> `Main> quickCheck prop_Insert
>   OK, passed 100 tests. 58% at-head,
>   at-tail. 22% at-tail. 4% at-head.`
>
> Note that a test case may fall into more than one classification.

(from [QuickCheck manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html))

For demanding the particular property of the input data, you may add `somePredicate data ==>` before the test body, as it is shown in the snippet above. Another example:

`prop_max xs = (not . null xs) ==> head (sort xs) == maximum xs`

You're right, this combinator throws away inappropriate cases. If that's undesired, you can make a `newtype` wrapper over the input type and redefine the `Arbitrary` instance for it (see examples of `Positive`, `NonEmpty` and so on [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Modifiers.html))

Comment: OK, so that nicely explains how to deal with generating the right data. Now how do I generate new test data inside a property?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675455/haskell-quickcheck-property-fails-tests-using-implications). Apparently it's `forAll`:

```
else forAll arbitrary $ \ baz -> fn2 foo bar baz
```

I just couldn't remember how to do it...

(This also has the nice feature of allowing me to specify a specific random data generator.)